# what happens when a c# .net using block fails?

Tags: c#, .net, block, using

If I have a using block, where I create an object (e.g. a FileStream object), and that object fails to create (returns null, throws an exception, etc.), does the code in the block still execute?

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    // do stuff with fs here
}
// do more stuff after
```

If the FileStream constructor were to return null (if the FileStream constructor always returns a valid object, let's just say for sake of argument that it is possible to return null), would the code inside execute? Or would it skip over the "do stuff with fs here" code?

Comment: What makes you think it will still execute rather than crashing???

Comment: A constructor that returns null??

Comment: @ken2k: As I see, this is just an example. Say that instead of a constructor, it is requesting the object to a service locator, a factory, or anything. In fact, writing `using(null){}` [compiles and runs fine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/03/danger-will-robinson.aspx)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) 
{
    // do stuff with fs here
}
// do more stuff after
```

is equivalent to:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
try
{
    // do stuff with fs here
}
finally
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)fs).Dispose();
    }
}
// do more stuff after
```

So to answer your question:

> If the FileStream constructor were to return null (if the FileStream
>   constructor always returns a valid object, let's just say for sake of
>   argument that it is possible to return null), would the code inside
>   execute?

Yes, it will.

Obviously everyone familiar with the C# specification knows that a constructor (no matter for which type) can **never** return `null` which kind of makes your question a bit unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

The exception would get handled as usual i.e. by the enclosing try...catch if you have one or by the system.

Answer (score 0):

If it throws an exception, it's definitely not going to execute. If no exception is thrown, it's going to try and execute the block. Though if it were to return null, my guess is it wouldn't get far before throwing an exception from inside and quitting.

Answer (score 0):

The code will execute regardless of that so you'll need to protect your code against it. Take for example this console application, the `WriteLine` will execute.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello.");
        }
    }
}
```